# Pandas: How to center the start of pandas bar in style with align

Tags: python, pandas

Is there away to center the bar in column,where -4 is colored and 3 is colored and zero is clear. It would be great if I could use two colors.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(-4, 4), columns=['A'])
df.style.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: You can try with seaborn [barplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/color_palettes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now:

[image]

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(range(-4, 4), columns=['A'])
    df.style.bar(align="mid")
```